# My magento site home page not indexed with google search

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, seo, google-analytics

I have launched a new Magento site. A simple CMS page is config as default home page. I have added the meta keywords and descriptions in that CMS page.

But the home page not indexed in Google search. I can't find the exact issues.
I hope someone can guide me with a solution it would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this issue?  I'm reviewing my site and I'm finding that the homepage is not in the sitemap.xml.  Maybe that's my issue, but it's almost a pure stock Magento so I'm not sure of the cause.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the option by following below path in Magento 2 admin.
Stores -> Configuration -> General (Left side) -> Design (section) -> Search Engine Robots -> Default Robots (Select)-> Select

```
1. INDEX, FOLLOW

2. NOINDEX, FOLLOW

3. INDEX, NOFOLLOW

4. NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW
```

Save the configuration as you need. clean and flush cache. You need to select option [1]. It will work.

Comment: Its already selected as INDEX, FOLLOW

Comment: Check answer from @Rama Chandarn and look if you have sitemap.xml. Also update link of sitemap in robot.txt. You can update robot.txt in admin.

Comment: Sitemap url already specified in robot.txt file

Comment: like http://example.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: yes and you can create it from admin. You can create from ADMIN -> MARKETING -> Site Map (under SEO & SEARCH)

Answer (score 1):

It may cause different scenario. Please check the link [home page not indexed with google search](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/definitive-list-reasons-google-isnt-indexing-site/118245/)

1. Your site Don’t Have a sitemap.xml
2. Your site Have Crawl Errors check in webmaster tool. Webmaster Tools → Select your site, → Click on “Crawl” → Click on “Crawl Errors”
3. Also check your Magento frontend meta tag index.